# Confused on Proposition 9.2.2 of JW Thomas (1D conservation law)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm confused on how to prove the following proposition from *Numerical Partial Differential Equations: Conservation Laws and Elliptic Equations* by JW Thomas:

> **Proposition 9.2.2**: If $v$ is a sufficiently smooth solution to the initial value problem defined by conservation law (9.2.1) [$v_t + F'(v) v_x = 0$] for $x \in \mathbb{R}, t > 0$ along with initial condition $v(x,0) = v_0(x), x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $v$ will satisfy
> $$ \hspace{3cm} v(x,t) = v_0 \big(x - t F'(v(x,t)) \big). \hspace{3cm} (9.2.7) $$
> To prove the above result, it is sufficient to differentiate solution (9.2.7) with respect to $t$ and $x$ and show that $v_t + F'(v) v_x$ equals zero.

I am confused by the sentence "To prove the above result...". If $v$ is a solution of the initial value problem, then wouldn't we automatically have $v_t + F'(v) v_x = 0$ *by definition*? Unless the last sentence or the proposition statement is incorrectly worded, I don't see how this makes sense.

If the statement of the proposition is indeed correct, how would I go about proving it?  I was able to verify the converse statement, i.e., that if $v: \mathbb{R} \times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function that satisfies
$$ v(x,t) = v_0 \big(x - t F'(v(x,t)) \big), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}, t > 0 $$

then $v_t + F'(v) v_x = 0$ and $v(x,0) = v_0(x)$. The proof method is exactly described by the sentence following the proposition statement, so perhaps the proposition was meant to be the converse statement?

Comment: The problem may want you to use uniqueness to conclude that such a $v$ is the *only* solution.

Comment: @eyeballfrog: Hmm, let me see if I understand you: So suppose $v$ is a solution of $v_t + F'(v) v_x = 0, \, v(x,0) = v_0(x)$. Then define $w(x,t) := v_0(x - t F'(v(x,t)))$ and $w(x,0) = v_0(x)$. Then since $w$ satisfies the IVP as well, by uniqueness we have $v = w$...Do I have that right?